# Property of convex combinations.

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

If $x = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i y_i$ with $a_i > 0$, $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = 1$ and $|x| \geq |y_i|$ why is it true that $x = y_i$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$?

I can see that $|x| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i |y_i| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i |x| = |x|$ which means that $|x| = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i |y_i|$. But how to I conclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i |y_i| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i |x|$$

Therefore

$$0 \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i (|y_i|-|x|) \leq 0$$

Thus:
$$0 \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i (|y_i-x|)\leq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i (|y_i|-|x|) \leq 0$$

Hence:

$$0 = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i (|y_i-x|)$$

Since all terms in this sum are nonnegative, therefore we conclude that $|y_i-x|=0$